# force switch to next firewall in symfony authentification

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to throw an exception (or anything) during the first matched firewall authentification process (in a AuthenticationEntryPointInterface) to say "Hey, even if it's my pattern url path, I am not concerned, check on the next firewall in security config" ?
(Symfony 6.2 here)

Comment: I know that we have `switch_user ` parameter on the firewall. you can check out the docs for it .. maybe it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally used RequestMatcherInterface. Therefore, the logic of moving to the next firewall is not handled in AuthenticationEntryPointInterface as I initially wanted, but in this interface, which can be defined at the firewall configuration level via the request_matcher parameter.